# Why are some edits highlighted in green color when I am convinced that I didn't make them?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was reviewing a suggested edit that I had submitted when I realized that both "show the rendered output diffs side-by-side" and "show the markdown source diffs side-by-side" were highlighting in green color fragments of text that I had not written in my edit.

In the following screenshot I have circled in red color two fragments of the edit which I am sure that I did not type.

[image: Screenshot of suggested edit]

Is it possible that the system is comparing my edit with a superseded edit by the OP?

If possible, I would like to know why this happens.

Thank you.

Follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15039892) to access the suggested edit.

Comment: After a second look at your screenshot, I realised my answer was wrong, so I deleted it. It is possible that an edit by the OP ended up being folded into your edit, though I'm not sure about the exact mechanics of that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You started editing within the grace period, the OP must have removed that line after you opened the editor but before you submitted your edit. As the OP's edit would have been folded together with the original revision during the grace period, it seemed like you added that text.

Comment: Yes, I recall that I started editing the question in a matter of seconds after it was published for the first time. Now it all makes sense to me. Thanks a lot for the explanation.